# Why is my self instance not getting passed in method

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code. 
class ResourceManagerSuspension is inheriting from class TestCase. TestCase executes tests alphabetically methods like testA will be executed before testB. 
so testLinkData method is executed before testSuspension and self.link is getting it's value in testLinkData. 
I am initializing a variable "self.link" and when method testSuspension gets executed it calls getQueryValues.

My question is why

"self.link" is not being passed in getQueryValues method ?
Can anyone explain how the self mechanism is working here, maybe I am doing something wrong?

```
class ResourceManagerSuspension(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):
        logger.info("=== Starting setup ===")
       # self.rm_obj = ResourceManager(agg='mapper-prefix1-aggs.A.m2-test.akamai.com')
        self.rm_obj = ResourceManager()
        self.rm_leader = self.rm_obj.get_rm_leader() 
        logger.info("RM lead target is %s" % (self.rm_leader))
        self.found = "" 
        self.link = ""  
        logger.info("self.link is : {}".format(self.link))
        logger.info("self in setUpClass is : {}".format(self.__dict__))         

    #the name should be get link number to get started etc
    def testLinkData(self):
        linkValues = {} 
        #get a random link  
        sqlquery = "select * from rm_links_debugonly where adjuster_reason not like '\%suspend\%' and ip=" + self.rm_leader + " and link!=0 limit 1"
        link_obj = self.rm_obj.get_link_info(query=sqlquery) 
        for row in link_obj:
            self.link = row.link
        self.getDynamicConfig()
        logger.info("self.link is : {}".format(self.link))
        logger.info("self in testLinkData is : {}".format(self.__dict__))

    def testSuspension(self):
        if not ResourceManagerSuspension.found:
            #get the 'control_reason' from "rm_link_load_control_debugonly" and 'adjuster_cap' from "rm_links_debugonly" before submitting the dynamic config 
            self.control_reason_without_config, self.adjuster_cap_without_config = self.getQueryValues()

            logger.info("param not present in the file, submitting with the param")
            self.rm_obj.dyamic_config_submit(fromLocation = self.rm_obj.dynamic_config_modified, to = self.rm_obj.dynamic_config_incoming)


       else:
           logger.info("param is already present, removing it and submitting the config")
           self.rm_obj.dyamic_config_submit(fromLocation = self.rm_obj.dynamic_config_modified, to = self.rm_obj.dynamic_config_incoming)
          logger.info("self.link is : {}".format(self.link))
          logger.info("self in testSuspension is : {}".format(self.__dict__))

    def getQueryValues(self):
       logger.info("self in getQueryValues is : {}".format(self.__dict__))
       logger.info("self.link is : {}".format(self.link))
```

The output of last line in code is

```
[05:55:39.709 test_suspension_2:  61  I] self.link is :
```

Comment: The indentation in the question is wrong. Please [edit] it so it looks like your code all the way through.

Comment: Also, relying on changes from other test functions isn’t good test design for a few reasons – it could easily be unsupported by your test runner. What is it?

Comment: edited the indentations

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests are supposed to be able to run independently from one another, entailing that `getQueryValues` should be able to run before or after `testLinkData`, but in your implementation, `getQueryValues` must run after `testLinkData` in order for the output you expect to be given.

To remedy this, you must write set-up utility methods that your test methods can call as they run, i.e. to give `self.link` a value independent of another test.

Comment: I am not sure if it's django. It's a home made unittest framework.
getQueryValues won't run unless it's called from a test<> method as it's a helper method. 

As to for self.link having a  value independent of another tests, hence I am initializing it in the setUpClass method.

Comment: @hitman99: Can you show what your test runner does to run a test, then?

Comment: The test runner is python's unittest. https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#testcase-objects